# Move "create and account" link in KoboToolbox Login form to Admin Panel

Tags: docker, kobo

I have been trying to locate that is there a way we can remove "Create an Account" link from home page/login panel and somehow create that link inside admin panel? In my case, I don't want everyone to get registered with my KoboToolbox but I want to add the user from Admin Panel and assign them roles accordingly?

Let me know if there is a way or any workaround for this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be better answered at https://community.kobotoolbox.org/, but KoBoToolbox has a setting called `REGISTRATION_OPEN` that you can disable through the Django admin interface. Find it at https://your-kobo-host/admin/constance/config/. See also https://github.com/kobotoolbox/kpi/pull/1736.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, in fact these are the essential (and only) parts of the answer: go to the Django admin interface (I posted an example URL for convenience), and modify the `REGISTRATION_OPEN` setting. The GitHub link was simply provided for reference as it's the pull request where I, the maintainer of KoBoToolbox, added the feature to disable registration. Thanks.